# zabbix frontend error mysql_connect, init_set

Tags: php, constants, frontend, zabbix

I run zabbix on brown and have some error:

> mysql_connect(): The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed
> in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead [include/db.inc.php:76]
>
> ini_set(): Use of mbstring.internal_encoding is deprecated
> include/locales.inc.php:26]

Comment: What version of Zabbix are you using? `mysql_` functions were removed in PHP7.

Comment: I using Zabbix 2.0.0

Comment: Which version of PHP are you using ? In addition to the question above, what is "brown" in here ? "I run zabbix on brown"

Comment: Sorry. I using PHP 5.6.21 (cli) (built: May  2 2016 23:27:53) and I run zabbix server on chrome. Thanks!